# System.Web.UI.WebControls.FontInfo proper usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I want to create a property on my class of type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.FontInfo`. However `System.web.UI.WebControls.FontInfo` does not have a public constructor of any kind.

I'm not sure how to create an instance of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.FontInfo`. Expectedly, I'm getting an "Object reference null" error when trying to use the property without initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiating a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style` object and using the `Font` property on that object as your `Font` object seems to be the accepted solution to using `FontInfo` in a custom control.

Source: [FontInfo property for ASP.Net components](http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fontinfoprop.aspx?msg=1388903)